# Not able to fetch email and profile details through Google oauth in AuthenticationManager_GetExternalLoginInfoAsync_WithExternalBearer

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, google-oauth, owin-middleware

While implementing Google oauth in of my website, I have encountered a problem where this API api/Account/RegisterExternal having function Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() returns null. After hours of searching I found the above function is using different Authentication type hence found the below function which works perfectly fine for the authentication.

```
private async Task<ExternalLoginInfo> 
AuthenticationManager_GetExternalLoginInfoAsync_WithExternalBearer()
    {
        ExternalLoginInfo loginInfo = null;

        var result = await Authentication.AuthenticateAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer);


        if (result != null && result.Identity != null)
        {
            var idClaim = result.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            if (idClaim != null)
            {
                loginInfo = new ExternalLoginInfo()
                {
                    DefaultUserName = result.Identity.Name == null ? "" : result.Identity.Name.Replace(" ", ""),
                    Login = new UserLoginInfo(idClaim.Issuer, idClaim.Value),
                    Email = result.Identity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email)
                };
            }
        }
        return loginInfo;
    }
```

But when I try to fetch the emails or authenticated user's info, its unavailable. Could anyone help either to fetch the email this way or how can I make Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() work so that it can return me the authenticated user's email address.